# Raspberry Pi systemd start script out of specific location?

Tags: raspberry-pi, systemd

so I have a script that I want to start out of systemd. However, the script needs to be started while being in a specific directory, because some modules cannot find the files in that directory otherwise. So when I start it manually i would do cd and then my directory and then start the script, but I now need to find a way to do this with systemd to start automatically. Help is greatly appreciated, I'm pretty new so still figuring everything out :)

Comment: Take a look at the [systemd.exec](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html) man page, where you'll find the `WorkingDirectory` option is probably what you want.

Comment: Now i feel stupid for not findig that myself... Thanks very much though, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the [`WorkingDirectory`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#WorkingDirectory=) and [`ExecStart`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStart=) directives. You will need to provide your own paths here as they’re not stated in your question.

```
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi
ExecStart=/home/pi/launchscript.sh
```